# Cucumber Bad File descriptor error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, cucumber, webrat

I followed the below link to setup selenium with windows

http://pragdevnotes.com/2010/10/31/using-selenium-with-cucumber-through-webrat-or-capybara-which-one-to-choose

When i run **cucumber `--tags @login_provider`**
And in env.rb file i set :-

```
config.mode= selenium
```

Then am encountering **Bad file descriptor `(Errno::EBADF) error`**
This error is caused when it encounters visit webrat method.
Can anyone help me in resolving this?

Thanks in advance!!